# Django - Redirect User to a page based on selection from a drop down menu

Tags: django, django-forms

I am attempting to use a drop down menu in django to allow a user to select an option from the menu and then navigate to at page.

Specifically.   I am building a small project management system as a learning project (i know i have many other issues here - I just want to get things functional first and then worry about style and removing the variables that are not needed).   I want the user to select a project from a drop down menu (this I can populate) and then navigate to a page that shows the details of the project.   I currently have this working by clicking on links, but want to make it where the users can select an existing project and see the details

The html form should take a user from the view_existing_projects view to the view_project view.   Right now I can transition views find, but the project_id is not getting passed

urls.py

```
url(r'^view_project/(?P<project_id>\d+)/$', views.view_project, name='view_project'),
```

html form

```
    <form method="POST" action="/view_project/{{ project.id }}"/>{% csrf_token %}
    <select name = "project_id">
    {% for project in projects %}
    <option value="{{ project.id }}" >{{ project.address1 }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
<input type="submit"  value="View Details" />
    </form>
```

views.py

```
def view_existing_projects(request, user_id):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    projects = ProjectSite.objects.filter(owner__id=user.id)
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['users'] = user
    args['projects'] = projects
    if request.method == 'POST':
        project_id = request.POST.get('project_id')
        args['project_id']= project_id

        return redirect('/view_project/', args,context)
    else:
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['users'] = user
        args['projects'] = projects
   return render_to_response('Bapp/manage_projects.html', args,context)


def view_project(request, project_id):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    user = User.objects.get(project_sites__id=project_id)
    site = ProjectSite.objects.get(id=project_id)
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['Users'] = user
    args['Project'] = site
    return render_to_response('Bapp/view_project.html', args,context)
```

Comment: try `print request.POST.get('project_id')` do you see `project_id`? BTW Don't use `render_to_response` use [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) instead. And the irony, you have declared a variable args and its a dict (kwargs) :)

Comment: Thanks for the input/advice - part of the fun of learning - I see the project id when it prints and i swapped in the redirect - i just cant get the project_id to get passed to the next view

Comment: How you have used the `redirect` with the desired URL?

Comment: Im passing it 'return redirect('/view_project/', args,context)' - which gets me to the right view - just without the project id getting passed

Comment: Show your `urls.py` file content

Comment: I updated the posting with the new redirect and the relevant url

Comment: Check my answer it should work now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

if request.method == 'POST':
    project_id = request.POST.get('project_id')
    return redirect(reverse('view_project', args=(project_id,)))
```

BTW another suggestion instead of hardcoding the URL path `Bapp/view_project.html` use [named URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) as I have used.

Comment: Indeed it did - much thanks.  By far the most difficult professional challenge I have undertaken today is learning how to "write" code….